# How can I record and load the Google Chrome's Network Tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I need to make performance tests on a website from a PC and have all the Chrome Devtools network tab information available in another PC where I'm developing.

How can I record such information in one PC and then load it in another PC?

I'm looking for something similar of the timeline recording/loading feature, but for the network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in the network panel on a record and select `Save as HAR with content`. Then on another computer you can use [one](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/) of [many](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-archive-viewer/ebbdbdmhegaoooipfnjikefdpeoaidml?hl=en) HAR viewers to analyze the data.